# How do you destructure a function from RTK Query's generated useQuery hooks?

Tags: reactjs, rtk-query

If `logIn` can be destructured from

```js
const [logIn] = useLogInMutation();
```

and be used with

```js
const handleLogin = async () => {
    const username = 'username';
    const password = 'password';

    await logIn({
        username,
        password,
    });
};
```

how do I perform a query similar to something like this

```js
const handleGetUser = async () => {
    await getUser();
};
```

from this

```js
const { data: user, isSuccess, isError, error } = useGetUserQuery();
```

Comment: [Docs?](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks#uselazyquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Export the `useLazyQuery` hook (`useLazyGetUserQuery` in this case)

```js
export const {
    useLogInMutation,
    useGetUserQuery,
    useLazyGetUserQuery,
    useLogOutMutation,
} = authApi;
```

2. Import and use the hook

```js
const [getUser] = useLazyGetUserQuery();

const handleGetUser = async () => {
    try {
        const user = await getUser().unwrap();

        console.log(user);
    } catch (err) {
        if (err?.status === 401) {
            console.error('Unautheticated.');
        }
    }
};
```

<sub>Thanks @Kapobajza</sub>

Comment: i get this error  "object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator)) "  const [getAllCnnections, {
    data,
    isLoading: loading,
    error,
    isFetching,
  }] = useGetAllConnectionsQuery(query-params, {
    //refetchOnMountOrArgChange: true,
  });